# When the Usual Set Class is Not Enough: A Weekend Warrior's Project

Tags: generics, collections, set, implementation, wiki

## Rethinking Sets

### Introduction

In C++, C#, Java, and Python, there are classes for defining an unordered collection of objects, [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/), [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and [set](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) respectively.  The trouble with this idea is that these classes are good for 'small' discrete sets.  Sometimes I want a set that exhibits a property, however if I list every possible element of that set, I will run out of computer memory.  An example of this would be the following:

- Consider the set of all double precision floats.  Constructing such a set would exhaust the memory of most computing devices and would take a great deal of time to populate.

There are many more examples of sets like this where the usual unordered collection of objects is not ideal or practical.  A set does not require (or demand) a vast memory requirement, whereas the the set types in C++, C#, Java, and Python when we want to consider very large sets require large amounts of memory.  Instead of using the usual unordered discrete collections like the ones above, why not create a class (or some type of object) that is more generic?

Forgive me if my vocabulary is not proper when I describe this, I am no computer scientist.  I am just a lowly grad student in math that wants to emulate how sets can be thought of in math.  For instance, the real numbers is a set that has more elements than the number of sub atomic particles in the universe.  Moreover, it is impossible to construct the real numbers by placing each element of the real numbers into a set like one would in the set constructs found in C++, C#, Java, and Python.

### The Alternative Set Object Proposal

The set object proposal has two parts: a qualitative description of this set and a description of set operations.

#### Qualitative Description

A set as two parts to it.  A generic object type, and a property.

1. Generic Object Type: The elements of the set must come from a domain.  In programming, a domain is usually some type of *object type*.  I'll give an some examples of *object types* found regularly in programming:

   - Primitive Data Types: int, bool, float, double, char, string, etc.
   - Fixed Arrays: data of a certain fixed size.  Here are some examples
   - Dynamic Arrays:  Vectors, lists, etc.
   - structs
   - classes
   - namespaces
   - void (I mean to say that I can construct an arbitrary set with any type of object)
   - functions that return a particular type of object
   - functions with certain input qualities (e.g. any function with 3 inputs, or a function with one integer input, etc)
   - another set
   - etc.
2. The Property of the Set:  The property determines whether an element of the Generic Object Type (1) is a part of the set. The property is a function that returns true or false.  True meaning that it is apart of the set and false if it is not apart of the set.

The advantage of (2) is that the property function *could* contain a discrete set of objects like we have already in C++, C#, Java, and python or we **could** just check if the element exhibits a property (e.g. is object X a float?).  The property function could have arbitrarily many inputs to determine whether an element is a property of the set (i.e. return true/false).  One should also consider that the property function should be flexible enough to handle any object as an input.  For example, one might try to test if a Cat object is an element of a set when the set's property function checks if a Horse object is taller than 6 feet.  In scenarios like this, the property function might throw an exception, however the property function should still return false.

#### Set Operations

1. ***Union***: a function that with 2 or more sets as inputs.  The inputs' property functions are P1, P2, ..., Pn respectively.  The Union function returns a new set whose property function is P1 or P2 or --- or Pn.
2. ***Intersection***: a function that with 2 or more sets as inputs.  The inputs' property functions are P1, P2, ..., Pn respectively.  The Intersection function returns a new set whose property function P1 and P2 and --- and Pn.
3. ***Compliment***: a function with the only input is a set.  Let the input set's property function be P1.  The Compliment function returns a new set whose property function returns false if P1 returns true; the property function returns true if P1 is false.  That is to say, this new set has the property function of NOT P1.
4. ***Relative Compliment***: a function that with 2 sets as inputs.  The inputs' property functions are P1, P2 respectively. The Relative Compliment function returns a new set whose property function is (P1 and NOT P2).
5. ***Cartesian Product***: Given to or more sets as inputs.   The function produces a second copy of the sets; the copied sets are placed in a list or array in the same order in which their corresponding original input sets had.

The drawback to this set implementation is that there is no deterministic way to show that *for any* two sets that one set is a subset of another using the generic object types and properties. Perhaps what is arguably the most famous example of this in computer science (and math) is whether P=NP.  In order for this to work, we would need to show that for any two property functions, P1 and P2, of any two sets, P1 implies P2 or P2 implies P1.  This isn't always easy to do.  *I'm willing to sacrifice this capability in this set object I'd like to construct.*

### A Set of Goals to Accomplish

I am not well versed enough to develop the set object in the *Qualitative Description* section, or the set Options in any these programming language.  I am calling on the StackOverflow community to help me in develop:

1. Develop the set object and set operations described above in various languages (not just C++, C#, Java, and Python).  I'm willing to accept that it may not be possible to create a set of a certain type of object (e.g.
2. On this page and/or on GitHub, present and offer the Set Object and Set operation code the code in various languages.
3. Use the set objects and operators in examples.
4. Detail what the set can't or can use for a generic object type.

## Code

This section have various implementations of a Set object.  If you have an implementation in another language other than one listed here, please submit it.  I (or any mod) can append it to the list.

### Java

#### Set Object Code

#### Set Operator Code

#### Set Object & Operator Examples

### C#

#### Set Object Code

#### Set Operator Code

#### Set Object & Operator Examples

### Python

#### Set Object Code

#### Set Operator Code

#### Set Object & Operator Examples

### C++

#### Set Object Code

#### Set Operator Code

#### Set Object & Operator Examples

Comment: Now we know there's no character limit to SO questions.  Thanks for treading where others dare not. :)

Comment: This is not a question. It's a large quote, and has no meaningful question. If there was a question, it would undoubtedly be asking for opinions, ideas on implementation, or some other discussion topic that's inappropriate here. Voting to close as "not constructive". Please don't post this kind of noise; it's nothing but clutter. Asking for suggestions for more content is not a proper use of SO. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically mentions this type of post as inappropriate here.

Comment: @Ken White The FAQ specifically states "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  

I wrote this because post because "There are many more examples of sets like this where the usual unordered collection of objects is not ideal or practical."  This long winded post poses a problem.  One of which I can describe yet I am not sure if it is possible to do at all.  If someone (or the community) can address this, it would benefit all.  I positioned the question to benefit all because it is a problem we all face. I do not find it open ended at all.

Comment: @Ken White  I want to develop this post as a wiki that addresses this problem.

Comment: The FAQ also says that "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. ", and "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here". (Actually, if you quote the entire section titled "What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?", your question hits them all.) This is NOT a wiki site, and should not be used as one.

Comment: What community would I ask then?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have an answer for that - all of the StackExchange sites have pretty much the same information in their FAQs. [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) includes the same information that SO does about discussion questions.

Comment: Innocent observation: this question would probably get more attention if you tagged it as: [set] [c++] [c#] [java] [python] instead. ;)

Comment: +1 because this is an interesting question, well described, with good potential. However, Ken White is correct that, as currently phrased, this isn't a good fit for StackOverflow (or anywhere in the StackExchange network). Perhaps if you could articulate more concretely some specific problem you're trying to solve, rather than the open ended discussion request that this currently is, that would make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: @DanielPryden,  thank you.  I think I will repose the question in a more "direct" fashion later on.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is closely resembled by [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`Range`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) and [`DiscreteDomain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html) classes. From the `Range` javadoc:

> A range (or "interval") defines the *boundaries* around a contiguous
>   span of values of some `Comparable` type; for example, "integers from 1
>   to 100 inclusive." Note that it is not possible to *iterate* over these
>   contained values unless an appropriate `DiscreteDomain` can be provided
>   to the `asSet` method.

See their [Ranges Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) article for more details and examples. The introduction to that article explains ranges more theoretically:

> A range, sometimes known as an interval, is a convex (informally,
>   "contiguous" or "unbroken") portion of a particular domain. Formally,
>   convexity means that for any `a <= b <= c`, `range.contains(a) &&
>   range.contains(c)` implies that `range.contains(b)`.
>
> Ranges may "extend to infinity" -- for example, the range "x > 3"
>   contains arbitrarily large values -- or may be finitely constrained,
>   for example "2 <= x < 5".